# How can i achieve the id of outer ul using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wants to achieve the id(i.e - `menu-right-2`) of outer ul in jquery when I found two.html link in browser. with following code.

```js
var fullpath = window.location.pathname;
var filename = fullpath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

var currentLink = $('a[href="' + filename + '"]');

var menuid = currentLink.parentsUntil('.menu-bar-right', 'ul').attr('id');
console.log(menuid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-bar-right">
  <ul id="menu-right-2">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="text nav-text">Yes</span>
      </a>
      <ul>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="two.html">
            <span class="text nav-text">Two</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try with `currentLink.closest('.menu-bar-right').find("ul").attr("id");`. But depending on your html, another answer would be better

Comment: Or `currentLink.closest('ul.menu-bar-right').attr('id');`

Comment: can't use closest as there are many menu-right-2. like menu-right-1,menu-right-2,menu-right-3,menu-right-4. its returning menu-right-1.

Comment: @JamesHibbard that would not work. There is no ul with class menu-bar-right

Comment: actually when i open two.html in url its should get menu-right-2 , when i open one.html it should get menu-right-1,  when i open three.html it should get menu-right-3.

Comment: There's no *computer/code* correlation between url "one.html" and menu link "menu-right-1" - you need to *convert* "one" to "1" - or, much easier, change your class to `menu-right-one`.  Then you can do a very simple: `menuid = "menu-right-" + filename;` and not bother with DOM navigation / matching on `[href=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parentUntil stops before the div you want

You mean this - closest STILL works well here

Multiple ULs in one div

```js
//var fullpath = window.location.pathname;
//var filename = fullpath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

const getULIdFromFileName = filename => {
  var currentLink = $(`a[href="${filename}"]`);
  var menuid = currentLink.closest('ul[id^=menu-right').attr('id'); // closest UL with an ID that starts with menu-right 
  return menuid;
};


var filename = 'one.html'; // test for menu 1
console.log(getULIdFromFileName(filename));
filename = 'two.html'; // test for menu 2
console.log(getULIdFromFileName(filename));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-bar-right">
  <ul id="menu-right-1">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="text nav-text">Yes</span>
      </a>
      <ul>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="one.html">
            <span class="text nav-text">One</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="menu-right-2">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="text nav-text">Yes</span>
      </a>
      <ul>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="two.html">
            <span class="text nav-text">Two</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="menu-right-3">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="text nav-text">Yes</span>
      </a>
      <ul>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="three.html">
            <span class="text nav-text">Three</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: and for this - https://codeshare.io/pqDMN4

Comment: See update. You can look for the closest UL with an ID that starts with menu-right

Comment: you are genius! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.closest()` method instead of `.parentsUntil()` to find the outer  element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-bar-right">
  <ul id="menu-right-2">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="text nav-text">Yes</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="two.html">
            <span class="text nav-text">Two</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  var fullpath = window.location.pathname;
  var filename = fullpath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

  var currentLink = $('a[href="' + filename + '"]');

  var menuid = currentLink.closest('.menu-bar-right').find('ul').attr('id');
  console.log(menuid);
</script>
```